# How do I create a responsive boostrap v3 carousel with fixed height that crops the image left and right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, slider, carousel

I've tried many answers I've found on here regarding this topic.

I'm using bootstrap v3 carousel. I'm using the default html and css. ( the html is taken from the carousel example template provided by twitter bootstrap )

I have a full width carousel on my home page. It works great. It resizes as any browser width as it should. What I would like;
- is for the carousel to do is to stay at the height I specify. 
- For the image to stay centred.
- For the width of the carousel to be responsive but for the images/slides to crop left and right.

A lot of the solutions I've found have suggested displaying the images in as css backgrounds. 
But I know what i require is possible with out using this option.

I've spent a lot of time experimenting with this trying to get it work. More than a few days! Any help would be greatly appreciated. From searching on various sites it seems other people would appreciate some help on this subject.

Please let me know if you would like me to post more details.

Comment: Please post this as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I got working :)

So after many more trials I got exactly what I described above. I hope people find this question and find it helpful. If you can't get it to work, maybe I can help?

Here is the code I used. (This is the css from twitter boostrap v3)

```
.carousel {
position: relative;
height: 685px;
} 
.carousel .item {
  height: 685px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-800px; /* Half the width of the image */
    height:685px;
    max-width:none;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```